# Make particular parameter mandatory in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components

We are creating a generic component in LWC. We need certain parameters to work it smoothly.

To do that, we are considering making the parameter mandatory so that the person/team invoking the component will see a save/deployment issue if it is not passing the mandatory parameter.

Example -
`lightning-datatable` has `key-field` as mandatory, so if we are not passing that field it gives an issue at save/deployment time.

Need to define a similar parameter like `key-field` in our component. So far I have not seen any specific ways to achieve that.

**Note - This component will be invoked from other aura/lwc components only**.

Answer (score 1):

There's no mechanism built into LWR/LWC to specify required attributes on save/deploy. You can specify required for attributes destined for App Builder, but this won't affect Aura/LWC references. You can write eslint rules to enforce compile-time required attributes, which Husky will run by default when installed into a project.

Comment: Will check with the custom es-lint rule.